# JavaFx not allowing me to setText() or add(), (only add nodes)

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to build a simple gui and I'm pretty sure I have set my build path correctly (from a youtube vid) but it's not allowing me to use '.setText()' or '.add()', however it is allowing me to use '.setTitle()' on my stage?

I have tried using the ctrl+space suggestions but it only offers me 'node (boolean)' or node(int index, node element).

```
    package application;

    import java.awt.Button;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

    public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    primaryStage.setTitle("this is a stage");

    Button button;
    button = new Button("click me");

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().add(button);
    primaryStage.show();
}
    }
```

Error: "The method add(Node) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Button)"

Yet, as I said above, the only option is node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a scene inside your stage. A stage is just a container that holds the scene which holds the scene graph(buttons, labels etc). Add the layout you made
as the root node in a scene like this

```
Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

Comment: Solved. I had two problems, this^, also  I imported 'javafx.scene.control.Button;' instead of 'java.awt.Button;'